# O365 user Unable to open office documents of SharePoint 2016 in Internet Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-365, internet-explorer

Some O365 users who recently got migrated from exchange server are unable to open SharePoint site office documents in internet explorer. They are able to open in chrome though.

I have checked reinstalling both IE and O365 , But no luck. I know something is blocking IE office addons to open the file in browser But don't know how to fix it.

here is the very famous error message he gets

"To open this workbook, your computer must have a version of Microsoft Excel installed and your Web browser must support opening files directly from Excel in the browser"

Comment: Your question i a bit unclear, are they opening documents on SharePoint online or SharePoint 2016 on prem?

Comment: They are having excel from O365 and opening documents of SharePoint 2016 on prem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user has access to the document. And also try to open the same document with some other full control account,in order to troubleshoot the issue.

It would be more clear, if you could provide a error screenshot which you face when opening the document.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "SharePoint OpenDocuments Class" managed add-on is enabled.

Internet explorer-> Tool -> Manage ADD-ons -> SharePoint OpenDocuments class : enabled

Besides, make sure you have installed office client on your computer.

[image]